# Adding generator functionality to a Python/C class

Tags: generator, python-c-api, python-c-extension

I have built a class in C with the Python/C API. I now have a requirement to iterate over the data items in the C blob. Returning a PyList is undesirable as length is >50K. Is there a way to provide generator-like functionality?

My one solution is to wrap the class in another pure python class and write the generator function at that level. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

According to [PEP 234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/), all you need to do is implement the `tp_iternext` slot in your python C class.